# Multiple Sets of Data

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to plot multiple sets of x and y data on the same plot with a legend.
This is the code I am using right now:

```
y = Table[f[c1_,inc_], {c1, 0, 3, 0.1}, {inc, {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6}}];
x = Table[{c1 + c1 + inc}, {c1, 0, 3,  0.1}, {inc, {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6}}];
```

Each column of y corresponds to a set of y data and each column of x corresponds to a set of x data.

I would like to obtain a plot with multiple curves, ideally with a legend. Ideas?

Comment: May you edit your question and add the definition for `f` and show the code you have tried.

Comment: Two things are going to be required: first, learn to use the `ListPlot` function. Next, learn to manipulate the lists to achieve the form that needed in the plot function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start. Since you declined to specify f[ ], I chose one.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 y^2; 
y = Table[{c1 + c1 + inc, f[c1, inc]}, {c1, 0, 3, 0.1}, {inc, {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6}}];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[y]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much this helped a lot. My function is a very large mathematica output so I don't think it would have been much help to you. Do you know how I could include a legend in the plot?

Comment: How about `ListLinePlot[Transpose[y], PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Comment: Hi! I get `ListLinePlot::optx: Unknown option PlotLegends in <<1.>>`

Comment: Maybe you are using an older version?

Comment: HI! I figured it out. I had to load the package. Your code works well. I noticed for the higher inc, that I have data points for higher x values. For example, in your graph some lines terminate earlier than others. Is there some way I could have them terminate for the same x value?

Comment: Try PlotRange->All.

Comment: The reason, I have it terminating for higher x values, is because the way the table is set up. The inc 0 data goes up to an x value of 6. Whereas the inc 0.6 data goes up to an x value of 6.6. I want the individual data sets to have the inc difference between them, but I would like to plot them up to the same x values.